# Initiating Azure Devops release pipeline from Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I’m trying to configure an Azure logic apps with an Azure Devops connector that would create a new pipeline release

The pipeline needs two variables, system and scope:

[image]

And looking at the  azure DevOps connector doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#create-a-new-release
[image]

How should I configure the name and value in the logic app ?, I tried this but it didn't work:

[image]
[image]

How to pass those variable to the release pipeline in Azure DevOps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding the connector from Visual studio will give an incomplete connector, deleting it and recreated it from the portal gave the key and value options

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)